# Invoke different function for each pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix

I want to invoke a different function each time when I make a call to `pthread_create`. I have four different functions which performs some processing on an array input by user. e.g ascending order, descending order etc. How can I do this inside loop as shown below for one function only?

```
 for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
     param[i] = ... ;   // Initialize parameter for thread i
     if ( pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, worker, & param[i]) != 0 ) {
        printf("Cannot create thread\n");
        exit(1);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to make an array of function pointers, and use `i` as an index of that array:

```
void* ascending(void* x)  { ... }
void* descending(void* x) { ... }
void* randomized(void* x) { ... }
void* unchanged(void* x)  { ... }

void* (*start_routines[])(void*) = {ascending, descending, randomized, unchanged};
```

Now you can do this:

```
if ( pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, start_routines[i%4], & param[i]) != 0 ) ...
```

Thread at index zero will start using `start_routines[0]`, which is `ascending`. Thread at index one will start using `start_routines[1]`, which is `descending`, and so on.

**Note:** If you do not like the "raw" syntax for defining arrays of function pointers, use a `typedef` to make your code more readable:

```
typedef void* (*pthread_start_routine)(void*);
pthread_start_routine[] start_routines = {ascending, descending, randomized, unchanged};
```

Comment: I saw a method of joining threads, but here I do not see any use of it because they are not dependent on each other by any means. What your thoughts on it? And please provide me with one awesome link of function pointers from your bookmarks. I'm new to C++ so both typedef and func ptrs are little complicated but I'll skim by looking at a good tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: @LetMeCodeYou Although the threads themselves may be independent of each other, the main thread is the one that's almost always dependent on the individual threads. Your main thread needs to join the individual threads, usually in a loop, to avoid exiting prematurely, and stopping the running threads before they get a chance to complete.

Comment: @LetMeCodeYou I do not have a good link that talks about function pointers. K&R book talks about them around page 100. There is also a tutorial on them [here](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex18.html). C++ has [pointers to member-functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members), which have an even scarier syntax.